# Generalisation of Sharifi's conjecture for Siegel varieties

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory, cyclotomic-fields, siegel-modular-forms, modular-curves

I recently learned Sharifi's conjecture in [this article](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/sharificonj.pdf) by F.Takako and K.Kato.

According to my understanding, this conjecture states that (the conjugation invariant) of the projective limit $\displaystyle \lim_{\leftarrow_{n}}\mathrm{Cl}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{n}})) [ p^{\infty}]$ is isomorphic, as a module on the projective limit of the Hecke algebra of level $p^{n}$, to (the conjugation invariant of) a quotient of the limit projective of $p $-adic cohomology of the modular curve $\displaystyle \lim_{\leftarrow_{n}} H^{1}(Y_{1}(p^{n}),\mathbb{Z}_{p })$.

**Question** If $Y_{1}(p^{n})$ is now the Siegel variety parametrizing the abelian varieties (with level condition), is it expected that (a quotient of) $ \displaystyle \lim_{\leftarrow_{n}} H^{1}(Y_{1}(p^{n}),\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ can be linked to Iwasawa module linked to a to a field extension (I don't really now what it should be, maybe a Selmer group...)?

**EDIT1:** As pointed out in the comments it should not be $H^{1}$ but $H^{\frac{g(g+1)}{2}}$ if $Y_{1}(p^{n})$ parameterize abelian varieties of dimension $g$.

**EDIT2:** Again, as noted in the comments, my question ultimately is "are their generalizations of Sharifi's conjectures to higher ranked groups?". I have to thank the user who helped me ask a coherent question in the comments.

Comment: Yes obviously, I feel silly.. My question is about $H^{\frac{g(g+1)}{2}}$ and not $H^{1}$.. Thank you.

Comment: Hey thanks again, I'll edit again but this time without trying to put my own (and too naive) guess. But now, after your comment, I feel like the answer to my question is simply no. But I'll leave it anyway :)

Comment: My comment may not be in the direction of the the "generalisation". I think what's more interesting is the relationship between $H^1$ and the cusp forms. Connection between cusp forms and class group is more Iwasawa theoretic (better to say related to Galois representations). But the previous part is more "geometric". It's what I think about these but I'm no expert.